# Process a list of objects and set them to a new Object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a database table with the below rows and fields:

```
Id name descr type freq
 1  A   desc   SMS  daily
 1  A   desc   Push weekly
 1  A   desc   InAp custom
 2  B   desc1  SMS  weekly
 2  B   desc1  Push daily
```

I am mapping these sql table to a POJO class called `List<Schedule>` with fields id,name,desc,type,freq using JPA.

Now I wanted to process this list in such a way that if name and description are same then I need to create a new POJO as below and set common values to fields and if different create as a list.

```java
class MyPojo{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String desc;
  private List<String> type;
  private List<String> frequency;
  //setters and getters
}
```

I am not sure on how to do such processings. I tried some using Streams with grouping by, and using comparator. But none of them worked. Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

```
    O/P= [“id”:”1”, “name”:”A”, “desc”:”desc”, “type”:{“SMS”,”Push”,”InApp”}, “freq”:{“daily”,”weekly”,”custom”}]  [“id”:”2”, “name”:”B”, “desc”:”desc1”, “type”:{“SMS”,”Push”}, “freq”:{“daily”,”weekly”}]
```

Comment: It seems that your table is not [normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @lance-java i have given only some part of table with changed values, but the table is normalized only. It is just that this table is only for fetching purposes, there wont be any changes in the data until or unless someone manually inserts the data. I wanted know how something like this can be done

Comment: ID is unique for each row, are you sure you want `id` on `MyPojo` (if so the lists will never have multiples)

Comment: your data structure is wrong as lance-java says, you basically want to do a group by, but in that way you loose your id field meaning ! If you try to do this in SQL, it's give you an error couse you cannot project a field out of group by condition, if you do not use an aggregation funcion like max, count, min !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like

```java
Map<String, MyBean> beanMap = new HashMap<>();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
   String name = rs.getString("name");
   String desc = rs.getString("desc");
   String type = rs.getString("type");
   String freq = rs.getString("freq");

   String group = name + "|" + desc;

   if (beanMap.containsKey(group)) {
      MyBean bean = beanMap.get(group );
      bean.getType().add(type);
      bean.getFreq().add(freq);
   } else {
      MyBean bean = new MyBean(name, desc, type, freq);
      beanMap.put(group, bean);
   }
}
Collection<MyBean> beans = beanMap.values();
```

Comment: This is the thing if we are using result set and get each fields but for me it is jpa object and mapping db values to List<Objects>, now wanted to convert this a list as a Single POJO in below json format {name:a, desc: abcd , type:[sms, push], freq: [daily,weekly]

Comment: well, regardless... just assume it's iterating the list of objects that map to the row. Same grouping logic applies

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which uses [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) on a stream of `Schedule` objects to convert from a `List<Schedule>` to a `Collection<MyPojo>`:

```java
record NameDesc(String name, String desc) {
    NameDesc(Schedule schedule) {
        this(schedule.name, schedule.desc);
    }
}

/*
 * {id=1,name=A,desc=desc,type=[SMS, Push, InAp],freq=[daily, weekly, custom]},
 * {id=2,name=B,desc=desc1,type=[SMS, Push],freq=[weekly, daily]}
 */
Collection<MyPojo> result = schedule.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NameDesc::new,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), schedules -> {
                    MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
                    myPojo.setId(schedules.get(0).id);
                    myPojo.setName(schedules.get(0).name);
                    myPojo.setDesc(schedules.get(0).desc);
                    myPojo.setType(schedules.stream().map(s -> s.type).toList());
                    myPojo.setFrequency(schedules.stream().map(s -> s.freq).toList());
                    return myPojo;
                })))
        .values();
```

This first groups the `Schedule` objects into a `List<Schedule>`, where `Schedule`s with the exact same name/description combination will be mapped as list elements of the same key.  It then transforms each `List<Schedule>` into a `MyPojo`, using the first item's ID, name, and desc; and all items' types & frequencies.  This results in a `Map<NameDesc, MyPojo>`.  Finally, the values of the `Map` are used, resulting in the desired `Collection<MyPojo>`.

## Test classes & data

The following are the classes and data I used to test the above solution with, based on your program description:

```java
static class Schedule {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String type;
    private String freq;

    public Schedule(int id, String name, String desc, String type, String freq) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.type = type;
        this.freq = freq;
    }
}

static class MyPojo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private List<String> type;
    private List<String> frequency;
    //setters and getters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public List<String> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(List<String> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<String> getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(List<String> frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s".formatted(id, name, desc, type, frequency);
    }
}
```

```java
List<Schedule> schedule = List.of(
        new Schedule(1, "A", "desc", "SMS", "daily"),
        new Schedule(2, "A", "desc", "Push", "weekly"),
        new Schedule(3, "A", "desc", "InAp", "custom"),
        new Schedule(4, "B", "desc1", "SMS", "weekly"),
        new Schedule(5, "B", "desc1", "Push", "daily")
);
```

Comment: my bad actually id will also be same so for same name, if another name is added then id will be different so the result should be like this id:1, name:A ,desc:desc, type:[], frequency:[]
id:2, name:B, desc:desc1, type:[],frequency:[]. This solution is always getting the values from 1st object after grouping but here it need to get from the subsequent objects if name and desc are different

Comment: @vyas Could you please clarify your question with the exact results you expect for the sample data you provided?  That will not only allow me to adjust my answer to address your question, it will also help others to do the same.

Comment: @vyas OK, thanks.  Then if I'm understanding things correctly, I believe my solution should get what you need.  It certainly gives your requested output for your sample input.  If I'm wrong, do you have an example input with desired output this solution doesn't work for?

Comment: I tried this but no its not working, its working for a list of Strings but if it is List<Objects>, it is not working, i had tried with list<objects>, for id there should be a List<Objects> something line {id:1, name: A, desc: desc preferences:[type:SMS, mode:SMTP, enabled:false], [type: PUSH, mode: IOS, enabled:true]}, {id:2, etc.,} but your code is giving not adding the list to existing list for same id, instead it is appending a new object

Comment: @vyas I have this working against a `List<Schedule>`.  I've added my test classes and data.  If it's not working with your data, perhaps there's some key difference between your data or classes and what I'm using.  Could you either share your classes in an edit to your question or take a look at mine and see if anything obvious jumps out at you?

Comment: list<schedules> is the data iam getting from db, if i want to map this to pojo like myPojo{id, name, desc, List<Pojo2>} and Pojo2{type, mode, enabled}. If i want to map the data from List<Schedules> to List<MyPojo>, i have used ur same logic iam getting output as {id:1,name:A,desc:desc,pojo2:{type:A, mode:B,enabled:true} and again a new object is being added with same id

Comment: @vyas — Without more detailed specifics, I'm not sure there's much more that can be figured out.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you're doing the right thing, but ... if you want to do exactly that, i can suggest this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<NameDescKey, List<DbRecord>> collect = Stream.of(
                new DbRecord(1, "A", "desc ", "SMS", "daily"),
                new DbRecord(2, "A", "desc ", "Push", "weekly"),
                new DbRecord(3, "A", "desc ", "InAp", "custom"),
                new DbRecord(4, "B", "desc1 ", "SMS", "weekly"),
                new DbRecord(5, "B", "desc1 ", "Push", "daily")
        ).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(dbRecord -> new NameDescKey(dbRecord.getName(), dbRecord.getDescr()))
        );

        List<MyPojo> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<DbRecord> dbRecordList : collect.values()) {
            MyPojo pojo = null;
            for (DbRecord record : dbRecordList) {
                if (pojo == null) {
                    pojo = new MyPojo();
                    pojo.setId(record.getId());
                    pojo.setName(record.getName());
                    pojo.setDesc(record.getDescr());
                }
                pojo.getFrequency().add(record.getFreq());
                pojo.getType().add(record.getType());
            }
            output.add(pojo);
        }

        for (MyPojo pojo : output) {
            System.out.println(pojo);
        }
    }

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class DbRecord {
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private String descr;
    private String type;
    private String freq;
}

@Data
public class MyPojo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private List<String> type = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> frequency = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
public class NameDescKey {
    private final String name;
    private final String desc;
}
```

tl;dr: first extract, than group by, after normalize taken first id per group !

[here the full module](https://github.com/stefanoriffaldi/stack-samples/tree/main/list-to-new-object)